# Does the series from $1$ to $\infty$ of $\frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, divergent-series

Does the series from $n = 1$ to $\infty$ of $\frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2}$ converge or diverge? Steps/tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $e^{1/n}$ is bounded. Does $\sum 1/n^2$ converge?

Comment: no because 1/n diverges.

Comment: Just because $\sum 1/n$ diverges doesn't mean $\sum 1/n^2$ diverges.

Comment: Shoot, um 1/n^2 is convergent because it's a p-series with a p value > 1

Comment: Yes it does. In fact, this particular series is known as the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), one that Euler is known to have solved. The answer - and the method Euler used - is very nice.

Comment: ^ to clarify, the Basel problem is the task of finding a closed form for the series. The problem of showing it converges is comparatively trivial.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate to using the fact that $\sum n^{-2} < \infty$, one can use the integral test:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2} dn = -e^{1/n} \Big|_0^{\infty} = 1 < \infty$$

Comment: Can you help me start the integration of that? Would you use some substitution or integration by parts...?

Comment: @Logan Substitue $u = 1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Converge.  $\max_n e^{1/n}$ is bounded.  $\sum_n n^{-2}$ converges.

Comment: Summands converging to zero does not mean a sum converges.

Comment: Right, should take more time to read.

Comment: Thanks but is there any specific step to do this or should I just know that e^(1/n) is bounded and that n^(-2) converges? I guess what I'm asking is what rules/theorems/etc. say that you can separate the multiplication and look at the two terms separately?

Comment: @Logan Yes you should "just" know that $\sum 1/n^2$ converges (this is almost always introduced from the beginning when covering convergence of infinite series), and therefore immediately want to **compare** the series $\sum e^{1/n}/n^2$ to that of $\sum 1/n^2$. It should be immediately intuitively obvious that $e^{1/n}$ is bounded; it's positive and decreasing starting from $e$ itself. Formally, since the partial sums of $\sum e^{1/n}/n^2$ are increasing and bounded above by $e\sum1/n^2<\infty$, the sequence of partial sums has a limit, i.e. the series converges.

Comment: Well, yeah.  I think there's a property that says something like $\int_1^\infty g(n) dn$ being finite for a nonnegative decreasing function $g$ implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)$ converging.  You have $g(n)=1/n^2$ and hence $\int_1^\infty g(n) dn = \int_1^\infty n^{-2} dn = 1<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my basic questions; I haven't learned the comparison test stuff yet. We are actually only on the integral test in my class right now. Thank you for your help!